# how to extract first word first letter and second word first letter using angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I have fullName that is coming from ts to HTML but in the view I have to show only First Letter from first Name and First Letter from last Name. For example

Here is my html code

```
{fullName}
```

and here is my ts code for that

```
fullName = John Doe
```

In output this is what I am looing

```
JD
```

Comment: It's a Javascript question

Comment: no@FábioRibeirodeCarvalho i want to use that in angular

Comment: Angular uses typescript, which is a superset of JavaScript. Do you mean you want to implement a pipe or some other angular specific thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const fullName = "Admin k L Name";

const split = fullName.split(" ");
const output = split[0][0] + split[1][0];

console.log(output);
```

---

If you want to reuse it the make a function, like this:

```js
const fullName = "Admin k L Name";

const nameReducer = (name) => {
  const split = fullName.split(" ");
  return split[0][0] + split[1][0];
};

const output = nameReducer(fullName); //  You can add this to the div
console.log(output);
```

---

**:**         .

Comment: I have a div tag where i need to place the output how i can do could you please help me

Comment: @Mr.M I have edited the answer, in the 2nd example, you can add the `output` to the `div`.

Comment: iam trying to implement the same in angular but I am getting lot of erors

Comment: @Mr.M It might be a syntax positioning error. I have updated it... It should work now!

Comment: cool but i only need first and last no middle name

Comment: @Mr.M I mentioned there ***Just for demonstration!***.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230960/discussion-between-mr-m-and-manas-khandelwal).